# How can I use x, y coordinate matrices to choose where a character appears in a string with python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, matrix, coordinate

I am attempting to make a simple maze game to test a NNS with genetic algorithms.
the maze for each test would use a matrix to hold the x, y points of things like barriers, the start, the end, and the player's current position. The main thing that I need help with is placing the right character in the right location in a string so when the strings of row 1-25 are read (probably with a for loop) it will read out a layout of the map. As an example, the barrier points 1,1 3,4 and 1,5 would look like this if an "o" is a space:
first string`|XoooX|`,
second string`|ooooo|`,
third string`|ooooo|`,
fourth string`|ooXoo|`.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which part of that is a problem?

Comment: i don't know how to get the x's in the right spot and/or in the right string. it must have something to do with using the y to choose a string, and a string concatenation to put the x in the right spot in the string, but I have no idea how to do this, nor how to pull them out of the matrices within the barrier matrix.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  Put your code example in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for something along the lines of this:

```
width = 6
height = 6
coords = [(1,1),(3,4),(1,5)]
print('\n'.join(['|' + ''.join(['x' if (x,y) in coords else 'o' for x in range(width)]) + '|' for y in range(height)]))
```

Using list comprehension, we can easily construct each row one at a time:

```
''.join(['x' if (x,y) in coords else 'o' for x in range(width)])
```

Basically, print an `x` if the coordinate contains something, otherwise use `o`.

Add the side bars in...

```
'|' + ''.join([...]) + '|'
```

`''.join()` is a [very useful function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) for this.

Then all we have to do is repeat this for each row, making sure to insert a line break between each row.

```
'\n'.join([...])
```